# How do I get the first 3 max numbers from tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

How do i get first 3 max number from `y_classe = tf.argmax(preds, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort and take the first 3:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = [1, 10, 26.9, 2.8, 166.32, 62.3]
sorted_a = tf.sort(a,direction='DESCENDING')
max_3 = tf.gather(sorted_a, [0,1,2])
print(max_3)
```

Comment: i am using this function inside prediction function.
preds = model([img_feat, ques_feat])
y_classe = tf.argmax(preds, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
sorted_a = tf.sort(preds, direction='DESCENDING')
max_3 = tf.gather(sorted_a, [0, 1, 2])

But its showing error:
ensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[1] = 1 is not in [0, 1) [Op:GatherV2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.math.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_pred = [[-18.6, 0.51, 2.94, -12.8]]

max_entries = 3

values, indices = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k=max_entries)
print(values)
print(indices)
```

```
tf.Tensor([[  2.94   0.51 -12.8 ]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[2 1 3]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=int32)
```